# Limit of $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\ xy\log(\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert)$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I need help to understand how we compute this kind of limit:

$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\ xy\log(\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert)$

I think we can use the squeeze theorem but I don't know how to bound the function, so I can use the theorem. If I suppose $0 \lt \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \lt 1$ then, but I'm struggle..

$ 0 \le \lvert f(x,y)\rvert = \lvert xy\log(\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert)\rvert$

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: To format $xy\log(\text{foo})$, use `xy \log(\text{foo})`  Lower case $l$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

$$xy\log(\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert)=\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}\cdot (|x|+|y|)\log(\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert)$$

then recall that as $u\to 0$

- $u\log u \to 0$

and by polar coordinates

- $\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}=r\cdot\frac{\cos \theta \sin \theta}{|\cos \theta|+|\sin \theta|}$

with

- $|\cos \theta|+|\sin \theta|\ge m>0$

Or as an alternative directly by polar coordinates

$$xy\log(\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert)=r\cos \theta \sin \theta\cdot \left(r\log r+r\log(|\cos \theta|+|\sin \theta|)\right)$$

Comment: Gimusi i have a question. In case i try to solve a limit with polar coordinates, and the result is a constant. Can i assure the limit is that constant?

Comment: @TheNicouU Can you give an example for this case?

Comment: want me to ask a question with an example? It might be interesting. Plus I do not want to interfere with this thread.

Comment: @TheNicouU Yes it is of course the best way! In such way you can obtain more advices.

Answer (score 3):

Use the AM-GM inequality:
$$
0\leq 2\sqrt{\lvert xy\rvert} \leq |x|+|y| \tag{1}
$$
from which
$$
0\leq 2\sqrt{\lvert xy\rvert}|\log(|x|+|y|)| \leq (|x|+|y|)|\log(|x|+|y|)|\tag{2}
$$
Setting $t(x,y)\stackrel{\rm def}{=} |x|+|y|$, we have $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} t(x,y)=0$ *(why?)* and therefore since $\lim_{t\to 0}t\log t = 0$ we get by the Squeeze theorem

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\sqrt{\lvert xy\rvert}|\log(|x|+|y|)| = 0\tag{3}
$$
and also 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\sqrt{\lvert xy\rvert} = 0 \tag{4}$$
also by (1) and the Squeeze theorem. 
Can you conclude?

Comment: Nice use of AM-GM!

Comment: Thank you! ${}{}$